# Ssl for bitcoind

Tags: cron, ssl, bitcoin

Hello I need to use bitcoin in my website I compiled it and I use php json rpc for communication with the server and I use crontab each minute for a check of the deposit but in bitcoin wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon it says:

> Enabling SSL on original client daemon JSON-RPC over SSL is strongly
>   discouraged

I have a basic SSL installed its dangerouse ? What is the good solution for make a secure wallet on ubuntu ?

If you have tutorial its good for me :)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it dangerous to enable OpenSSL?

No, not really. Firstly, bitcoin comes with its own OpenSSL library statically linked, so the version you have installed doesn't matter. Secondly, enabling RPC SSL can be a good way of hardening your server.

The point that page is trying to make, I think, is that

1. Enabling SSL doesn't remove the need to choose a good RPC password, and
2. If the PHP script and the Bitcoin instance are on the same computer, encrypting the link between them doesn't change anything.

#### How to set up SSL

Add this in bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcssl=1
rpcallowip=<server that will issue commands>
```

#### How do I make a secure wallet?

That's a really complicated question. I have a couple of broad pieces of advice.

1. Run as few services as possible.
2. Limit the amount of Bitcoin in your "hot wallet."
3. Wherever possible, hold public keys instead of private keys. For example, you can use a client like Electrum which lets the server hold an extended public key instead of an extended private key, which means that you can accept Bitcoin without (the server) being able to spend it.
4. Use a service that monitors the addresses in your wallet and alerts you if a lot of them move in a short period of time.
5. Enlist the help of a service like BitGo, which would control one of the keys to a multisig account, and act as a second line of defense.

PS. This question would probably be best answered over on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com. (I'm one of the mods there.)

Comment: Thanks you Nick yes the php script and bitcoind are in the same machine but u conseil me to use bitcoind or API from blockchain.info or its the same ? [https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api](https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api)

Comment: I would suggest that you use bitcoind.

Comment: Ok thanks for all guy and sorry for my little english